# Convert three letter month abbreviation to number?

Tags: microsoft-excel, date

Is there an excel function for converting a three letter month abbreviation (such as FEB, APR) to a number? I've been using a mapping table and then using v-lookup from there, but curious if there's a function or faster way.

Thanks!

edit to clarify: this is one column that has the three letter month abbreviation hardcoded in (i.e. it is not part of a longer date)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use MONTH() and create a pseudo date for it:

```
=MONTH(DATEVALUE(A1&" 1, 2017"))
```

[image]

---

Or another variation on the same theme:

```
=--TEXT(DATEVALUE(A1 & "1, 2017"),"m")
```

---

One more note: `DATEVALUE` can be replaced by `--` in both formula.

```
=MONTH(--(A1&" 1, 2017"))
```

and

```
=--TEXT(--(A1 & "1, 2017"),"m")
```

Answer (score 0):

Excel natively supports this using cell formatting. If you write a date, you can format the cell to show the month by 3 letters, but the value will actually be the month's number.

Comment: To clarify, my case is where the three letter abbreviation is the hardcoded into a column as the only value

Answer (score 0):

For me all the solutions proposed throw an error:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

But to be fair you can just do this:

`=IFS(LOWER(A1)="jan",1,LOWER(A1)="feb",2,LOWER(A1)="mar",3,LOWER(A1)="apr",4,LOWER(A1)="may",5,LOWER(A1)="jun",6,LOWER(A1)="jul",7,LOWER(A1)="aug",8,LOWER(A1)="sep",9,LOWER(A1)="oct",10,LOWER(A1)="nov",11,LOWER(A1)="dec",12)`

OR:

`=(FIND(LOWER(A1),"janfebmaraprmayjunjulaugsepoctnovdec")-1)/3+1`

[image]

Answer (score -1):

This is how to convert `01JAN1900` to `1/1/1900`

- split the original date into 3 separate columns using the functions `Left` `middle` `right`.

  This should look this:

  [image]
- Next link the 3 cells using  `=G2&"-"&H2&"-"&I2`. This will put the dates in an excel format.
- Next copy the column and paste values.
- You can now right click on cell and format the date to desired format.

Comment: The question is about a cell containing a three-letter text value (such as “FEB” or “APR”). If you want to answer a totally different question, then [***ask*** it as a new question](/questions/ask) and post your answer there. The above is not an answer to this question.   P.S. A correct answer to this question has already been posted.